# adding a logging configuration on container in FargateTaskDefinition causes a cyclic reference in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm having an issue with cyclic references in CDK. Here's some context on the CDK application I'm working on:

- I am building a reusable high-level CDK construct library that can be used to deploy web applications called [`django-cdk`](https://github.com/briancaffey/django-cdk)
- This is mostly for demonstration and learning purposes
- I have done something similar using Terraform modules [`terraform-aws-django`](https://github.com/briancaffey/terraform-aws-django) and I'm trying to build the exact same functionality with CDK
- In a previous iteration of my `django-cdk` project, I grouped all resources into a single stack
- I'm now trying to split out resources into different stacks that can be deployed independently
- To start small, I have simply split the single stack into two stacks: a `base` stack and an `app` stack
- The `base` stack is for long-lived resources (like VPC, RDS, IAM Roles, Load Balancer, Security Groups, etc.)
- The `app` stack is mostly for ECS resources (ECS Cluster, Services, Tasks and also target groups and listener rules for the load balancer)
- The `base` stack passes several values to the `app` stack that the `app` stack needs (like the VPC, Roles, SGs, RDS, etc.)

When I try to run `cdk synth` on the base stack, I get an error like this:

```
Error: 'TestBaseStack' depends on 'TestAppStack' (TestBaseStack -> TestAppStack/App/ApiService/TaskDefinition/api/LogGroup/Resource.Arn) Adding this dependency (TestAppStack -> TestBaseStack/Base/RdsInstance/RdsInstance/Resource.Endpoint.Address) would create a cyclic reference.
```

If I remove the `logging` configuration on the container in my `FargateTaskDefinition` (as I have done [here](https://github.com/briancaffey/django-cdk/blob/main/src/constructs/internal/ecs/web/index.ts#L51-L80), I am able to synthesize the `base` stack correctly.

I'm not sure why the `LogGroup` in the `app` stack makes the `base` stack dependent on the `app` stack. The `base` stack should not have a dependency on the `app` stack since the `app` stack is built on top of the `base` stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Put the ECS task execution role in same stack as the logging setup

The `AwsLogDriver` in `AppStack` (specifically, `grantWrite` in the `bind` call) wants to modify the `BaseStack` ECS execution role's default policy, but can't without introducing a cyclic dependency. [CDK source:](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-ecs/lib/log-drivers/aws-log-driver.ts):

```js
export class AwsLogDriver extends LogDriver {
    // ...
  public bind(scope: Construct, containerDefinition: ContainerDefinition): LogDriverConfig {
    // ...
    this.logGroup.grantWrite(containerDefinition.taskDefinition.obtainExecutionRole()); // <- this is causing your problem
    // ...
  }
}
```

`grantWrite`'s success or failure depends on whether the grantor construct (the log group) can add an inline policy in the grantee's (task execution role) stack:

- ❌ if the grantor is in a stack that *depends on* the grantee's (your case)
- ✅ if the grantor is in a stack that *does not depend on* the grantee's stack (doesn't work for you)
- ✅ if the grantor is in the *same stack* as the grantee (works for you)

If you don't want to co-locate the ECS roles in `AppStack`, a workaround can trick the CDK into adding the policy to `AppStack` rather than `BaseStack`

- ✅ if the grantee is imported from outside the app, the policy is added to the grantee stack

```js
// AdhocApp constructor
// pass to WebService after modifying its props to accept IRole instead of Role
 const roleDisguisedAsImport: IRole = Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'DisguisedFromRoleArn', props.executionRole.roleArn);
```

Note that this behaviour holds for CDK's [grant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.Grant.html) pattern in general (i.e. `bucket.grantWrite`), rather than being anything specific to ECS or log groups.